# Can't get Oauth facebook cookies using Koala for connecting to Facebook (with Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, cookies, oauth, koala

I'm using Rails 3.0.9.
Trying to login to my (localhost) site through Facebook.

My init params on the login page:

```
FB.init({
      appId : '<%= FB_APP_ID %>',
      status : true,
      cookie : true,
      xfbml : true
});
```

The login button works, I get the Facebook login popup and I can successfully log in to Facebook. 
Then the following event is reached:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {
    if (response.session) {location.href= ...}
```

And I'm being redirected to the wanted location.
But - can't get any cookies of "fbs_" or "fbsr_" like the Oauth is looking for at: get_user_info_from_cookie(cookies)

My cookies = {}, nothing there.
In a few occasions, I recall I did have some facebook cookies there, I can't reconstruct such case, but anyway, it didn't include the "fbs_" ones, only others.

Also, after logging in, when I go back to Facebook tab on the browser and refresh, it does show me my Facebook page, but after a second, it shows a popup says "you need to log in". In my app though, it still knows to keep directing me to the wanted href, like needed when a user is logged in.

I would really love to hear if you have anything that can help me... :-)

Thanks,
Moozly.

- Just got the scenario with some Facebook cookies again (still not by the wanted names). Got the following names: "datr", "locale", "locale", "reg_fb_gate", "lu".
  But even to these I can't get to with the Rails cookies param - cookies["dart"] returns null.
  cookies param only shows the cookies with the host of localhost (which contains data when I'm logging in (with Clearance) - the regular login procedure to site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to update to say that I had solved my problem:

1. I had added to the init the param: `oauth : true`:

   ```
   FB.init({
       appId : '<%= FB_APP_ID %>',
       status : true,
       cookie : true,
       xfbml : true,
       oauth : true
   });
   ```
2. Apparently, there is a bug with adding the parameters added in
   js.src, so I removed them(!) and problem was solved:

   ```
   (function(d, s, id) {
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" //removed: #xfbml=1&appId=<%= FB_APP_ID %>";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }
   (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
   ```

That solved the cookies problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use localhost for facebook development, add "127.0.0.1 localhost.local" record to your /etc/hosts file, change domain in application settings in developers.facebook.com and point browser to this url - it works flawlessly